# Change label or span value based on the checkboxes selected in asp.net webgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a webgrid which has a checkbox for each row. I need to calculate cart total based on the number of checkboxes that are selected.

My webgrid looks like:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
htmlAttributes: new { id="gridCartItems", style="max-width:60%" },
tableStyle: "webGrid",
       headerStyle: "webgridhead",
       alternatingRowStyle: "webgridalt",
       columns: grid.Columns(
       grid.Column(columnName: "TransactionType", header: "Type", canSort: true),
       grid.Column(columnName: "ItemNumber", header: "Item No.", canSort: true),
       grid.Column("Price", "Price", canSort: false), 
       grid.Column( header: "Select", format: @<text><input name="selectTextBox" type="checkbox" class="selectitemcheckbox" checked="checked"
           value="@item.ItemId" onclick="selectCartItem()" /></text>)
    ))
```

Total Cart Price looks:
   Total cart value: $ @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Total )
I will enclose it in span so that I can update the value using jquery.

By default all the checkboxes are checked, if a user unchecks a checkbox, then the total cart value needs to be updated.

I was able to access the properties of all the checkboxes by:

```
    $('tr .selectitemcheckbox').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        }
     });
```

I don't know how to access the Fee for the corresponding row in the webgrid and then add it to a variable to calculate to the total and show it in the page.

How can I do this and update the total accordingly?